# How to pass parameters into sql server UDF and have them cached

Tags: c#, sql-server, caching, user-defined-functions

I have a `UDF` function that calculates the "status" based on other field values passed in as parameters. I have made this using `C#` as a sql server project.

Not the actual function, but my problem as a simpler example :

`MyUdf(int a,int b)` :

```
return a+b
```

But I want :

return `a+b+c`, where `c` is a predefined value, retrieved from another table as a parameter so it can be changed later.

Problem is two fold :

**1) How to load this value from another table in a `UDF`?**

and more importantly...

**2) How to cache the value for later so that it is not retrieved for every row as that could be a performance issue.**

I am not looking for a solution, but for tips on how to proceed.

**My Actual function :**

```
[SqlFunction]
public static string CalcBDAlert(DateTime currentTime, string status, DateTime prevMilestoneAt, DateTime nextMilestoneAt)
{
    // quick process
    if (status == "Finished")
    {
        return "4,...";
    }
    else if (status == "Cancelled")
    {
        return "5,...";
    }

    #region Un-Allocated
    if (status == "Un-Alloc.")
    {
        var minPassedSinceMilestone = (currentTime - prevMilestoneAt).TotalMinutes; // milestone was start, creation of call.

        if (minPassedSinceMilestone < 15)
        {
            return "3,...";
        }
        else if (minPassedSinceMilestone < 30)
        {
            return "2,>15 Min";
        }
        else if (minPassedSinceMilestone < 35)
        {
            return "1,>30 Min!";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0,>35 Min!!";
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Allocated
    else if (status == "Alloc.")
    {
        var minPassedSinceMilestone = (currentTime - prevMilestoneAt).TotalMinutes; // milestone was allocation of engineer.
        var minRemTillNextMilestone = (nextMilestoneAt - prevMilestoneAt).TotalMinutes; // next milestone is ETA, predicted arrival time.
        var percentageTillNextMilestone = minPassedSinceMilestone / minRemTillNextMilestone;

        if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 0.90)
        {
            return "3,...";
        }
        else if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 0.95)
        {
            return "2,90-95%";
        }
        else if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 1)
        {
            return "1,>95%!";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0,>100%!!";
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Arrived
    else if (status == "Arrived")
    {
        var minPassedSinceMilestone = (currentTime - prevMilestoneAt).TotalMinutes; // milestone was arrival of engineer.
        var minRemTillNextMilestone = (nextMilestoneAt - prevMilestoneAt).TotalMinutes; // next milestone is completion of work.
        var percentageTillNextMilestone = minPassedSinceMilestone / minRemTillNextMilestone;

        if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 0.90)
        {
            return "3,...";
        }
        else if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 0.95)
        {
            return "2,90-95%";
        }
        else if (percentageTillNextMilestone < 1)
        {
            return "1,>95%!";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0,>100%!!";
        }
    }
    #endregion

    return "-1,Unknown";
}
```

I would like to parametrize and cache the percentages (.9, .95, 1) and minutes (15,30,35) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, udf itself can be kind of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myUdf 
(
    @a INT,
    @b INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c INT
    SET @c = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM my_table)
    RETURN @a + @b + @c
END
GO
```

What about caching - you don't have to care about it at all, rdbms will do it for you. Sql server keeps in memory some selection results, execution plans etc, so if your udf will execute often enough - sql server cache it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if it is possible to access other tables like this when designing the function using CLR / C#?

Comment: SQL Server does not cache selection results.

Comment: @MuhammadA why not? All you do using c# is a query to DB